# spotfire- showing column based on conditions

Tags: spotfire

I have two visualization below. Is there anyway to combine those two together and show `user_name` and `service_id` based another column "Type".

For examples if `[type]="user"`, this table will show "requestor name" and "user name". if `[type]="service"` then this same table will show "requestor name" and "service id"

[image: sample data table]

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Is this in a table, or cross-table, or...? Does each row in your data table contain all three columns, and only the necessary ones are populated? Can you post a sample data set?

Comment: yes, i want to populate certain columns based on one indicator column. i have edited my question including a data table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 3 ways you can approach this.

You can create a calculated column using one of the expressions below and use this column in your visualization.

**Option 1**

```
case 
  when [user_name] is null or [user_name] = "" then [service id] 
  else [user_name] 
end
```

**Option 2**

```
If(([user_name] is null) or ([user_name]=""),[service id],[user_name])
```

**Option 3**

You can use one of the expressions above in the category axis of your expression.

Comment: thank you it works. but i found that this method does not work in a cross table. do you know why? can i make some adjustment to make it work in a cross table?

Comment: @Ben, you need <> around the expression on the category axis of a cross table. `<If(([user_name] is null) or ([user_name]=""),[service id],[user_name])>`

Comment: Awesome @BenWang glad to help. Good luck